# Airy function zeros.

Tags: real-analysis, airy-functions, lagrange-inversion

I'm studying the Airy functions, and I got particularly interested in the behavior of the real zeros. I was wondering if there's some formula to express the n-th zero of the Airy functions, since they seem to have such a regular behavior, where for n-th zero I mean counting zeros in $\mathrm{Ai}(-x)$ and $\mathrm{Bi}(-x)$ from $x=0$.

Let $\zeta_n$ be the n-th zero of, for example, $\mathrm{Ai}(-x)$, I also suspect that $\zeta_n\sim \alpha n$ where $\alpha$ is some positive real constant, but reading [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265050/how-to-obtain-an-asymptotic-formula-for-the-zeros-of-the-airy-function-a-i-fo) I don't think it's true at all anymore.

I thought I could use Lagrange's inversion theorem to find some formula here, given that

$$
\mathrm{Ai}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)\mathrm{d}t
$$

and expanding $\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right)$ using Taylor series, but I tried and it seems too difficult.

Do you have maybe even some reference to look at?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe of interest at the [Math Overflow stack](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265050/how-to-obtain-an-asymptotic-formula-for-the-zeros-of-the-airy-function-a-i-fo).